# Send-Q column in netstat vs ss output

Tags: bash, networking, sh, netstat, ss

I am using netstat to retrieve the maximum size of the syn backlog from each listening socket. I read the following from the documentation:

> Send-Q
>
> Established: The count of bytes not acknowledged by  the  remote  host.
>
> Listening: Since Kernel 2.6.18 this column contains the maximum size of the syn backlog

However, when I run `netstat -ntpl`, the Send-Q column only contains zeroes, while the output of `ss -ntpl` contains the expected results.

Although I know that `ss` should be used instead of `netstat`, why do the results differ between `netstat` and `ss` and how can I get the expected results with netstat?